Добрый день, кто-нибудь может помочь мне с s3 bucket cloud.ru evolution на .net c#?
Хочу сделать рест для s3 бакета на cloud.ru.
Проблемы с подключением через .net cli и sdk.
Смог подключиться через cyberduck, потому что у них там свой конфиг.
Сам почитал конфиг, и кроме региона и того, что нужно использовать tenant id:access key вместо access key, не узнал.
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Попробуйте так:
var _s3client = new AmazonS3Client(
    configuration.S3Key,
    configuration.S3Secret,
    new AmazonS3Config { 
        ServiceURL = "https://s3.cloud.ru/", ForcePathStyle = true,
        AuthenticationRegion = "ru-central-1" }
);

configuration.S3Key в формате Tenant:secretKey (так же как в cyberduck).
